# How to secure backend resources of an AWS EC2 hosted MEAN stack app from being publicly accessible

Tags: angular, mongodb, docker, amazon-ec2, mean-stack

I am deploying a MEAN stack application on an AWS EC2 instance using three separate Docker containers for each component (Frontend (NGINX), Server (Express), Database (MongoDB). Everything works, but I need to open each component's port to the certain user's IP address. Since I don't know each user's IP and IPs might change, I need to set everything to public access within the instance's Security Group, which is obviously bad practise especially for the database. My approach was to set the frontend to public and the other components to be accessible only by the frontend, but that didn't work out so far.
Is there a way how to host a MEAN stack application with only the frontend's port being publicly accessible? Or do you know any other practises how to secure your backend resources from being publicly accessible?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How exactly "didn't that work out so far"? You're right, you only expose the web server(s) publicly, the database must be accessible only from the web servers. That's it. How have you tried setting that up and how'd it fail?

Comment: Manually setup a reverse proxy on nginx or use a load balancer that has public facing IPs that is attached to your web server that proxies requests back to your instance.

Comment: @nullptr.t How many more servers do you need here? There's already one nginx involved.

Comment: @deceze Can't the reverse proxy just be configured on the same instance that he is using?

Comment: @nullptr.t I'm questioning what you need another proxy for in the first place.

Comment: @deceze I configured the instance's SG accepting only the instance's IP on the ports of backend server and database, so only the NGINX was fully publicly accessible, but that didn't work out. The frontend "frame" appeared, but everything else depending on provided data was missing which ended up in a timeout. I assume that needs to be done within the source code?

Comment: @nullptr.t Formerly, I tried to set up a reverse proxy within the NGINX config, but that never worked out and effected CORS errors on backend server side, so I missed the proxy out and send the requests directly to the backend server, which works fine at all. Do I need to set up another NGINX only for the proxy or can I add it to the conf file?

Answer (score 0):

> but I need to open each component's port to the certain user's IP address

Create a [bastion host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host) running SSH, allow access to *that* host from the Internet, and allow access *from* that host to backend servers.

Comment: Do you have a tutorial how to set up such a bastian host for that specific constellation?

Comment: It is simply a server that allows incoming SSH access.